# yii2 string validation using substr() in comparing attributes of two related model

Tags: arrays, string, validation, yii2-basic-app

I have this two table:

Region table

```
create table if not exists Region (
    id int(2) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(40) unique not null,
    code varchar(9) not null,
    primary key(id)
    );
```

Province table:

```
create table if not exists Province (
    id int(2) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    region_id int(2) unsigned not null,
    name varchar(40) unique not null,
    code varchar(9) not null,
    primary key(id),
    key region_id(region_id),
    constraint province_region_id foreign key(region_id) references region(id)
);
```

sample data:

region_code:  010000000

province_code: 010100000

they are related coz they have the same first two character

ive created a partial custom validation but i cant finish it and even don't know if using substr() with arrayhelper combination is okay

```
public function modelCodeValidator()
        {
            $regCode=>substr([Arrayhelper::map(Region::find()->all()->,'id','code')],2);// specifying first two character of region.code
            $provCode=>substr('code',2);//specifying first two character of province.code


        return [$regCode=$provCode];
    }
```

on this custom validation, rule() would be:

```
['code','compare','modelCodeValidator' don't know next]
```

first two character of region_code should match/equal to the first two character of province_code.  by doing this user will notified that they could only enterered province code belonging to a particular region.please help

Answer (score 0):

Try by something like this..

```
public function rules()
    {
          return [
              ['code', 'modelCodeValidator'],
          ];
    }

public function modelCodeValidator($attribute, $params)
{
     // Write your coding stuff here    
   if (YourModelName::findOne(['your_model_field'=> $attribute]) {
        $this->addError($attribute, \Yii::t('view', 'The fields don't match.'));
   }
}
```

take a look here :-> 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#client-side-validation

Comment: this is how tried to my model:

public function rules();
  ['code','modelCodeValidator'],

public function modelCodeValidator()
 {
  $regCode='region_code';
  $provCode='code';
  $ret=strncmp($regCode,$provCode,2);
  
  if ($ret==0, Region::findOne(['region_id'=>$attribute])){
   $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('view','The fields do not match.'));
  }
 }
i can't get away coz  i know there's something wrong in my code, please help to modify it

Comment: @CristinaJesuitas : wrong... se what i did in answer... u just need to put your logic in side modelCodeValidator function